# Applet button click not working

Tags: java, button, applet

When I click the buttons on applet I get no response. **I had got output earlier - then I commented this part did some other stuff.**  Now again when I got back to it, it doesn't work no matter what I do.

```
public class main extends Applet {

    TextArea display = new TextArea();
    TextField input = new TextField();
    Button send;
    Button connect;

    String message;
    Socket cli = null;
    Socket client = null;
    time updatetime;
    Start_server start_server=null;

    public void init() {

        send = new Button("send");
        connect = new Button("Start");

        Panel keys = new Panel();
        keys.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        keys.add(connect);

        Panel south = new Panel();
        south.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        south.add("West", keys);
        south.add("Center", input);
        south.add("East", send);

        Label title = new Label("Lamport", Label.CENTER);
        title.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add("North", title);
        add("Center", display);
        add("South", south);

    }

    public boolean action(Event e, Object o) {
        if (e.target == connect) {
            display.append("connected");
        }
        else if(e.target == send) {
            display.append("sent");
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `public class main ..` a) 'main' is a terrible name for an applet class. b) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently. 2) `.. extends Applet {` Don't use AWT components in this millennium.  Use Swing.  3) Don't use deprecated methods.  Check the JavaDocs for the replacement. 4) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: all the code i wrote is specifically for a purpose... so do you have any specific answer ?

Comment: *"all the code i wrote is specifically for a purpose..."* Good, good..  was that comment supposed to address any of the 4 points I made?  If so, which one, and how?  *"so do you have any specific answer ?"*  So did you notice the area beneath our comments that starts with "3 Answers"?  So did you notice the top-most answer?  So did you notice who posted it, some 23 hours ago?  So are you starting to feel foolish about now? ;)

Comment: thanks for all your interest in my code and so much valuable suggestions...... now maybe you might even teach me how to "use Swing" that will be a great help advisior !

Comment: *"Finally i rewrote the entire code and it magically worked"*  There is no magic about it.  Until you understand what happened and correct it, this problem will continue to manifest every time  the applet code is changed.  *"now maybe you might even teach me how to "use Swing"*  Sure, [here you go](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Answer (score 1):

Buttons aren't magically able to do anything unless you give them code that lets them do things, and this is done by adding an ActionListener to the button. I don't see anywhere where you do this, and this of course is the solution to your problem. Have you read the tutorials on this before writing this code as it is all well described in tutorials and in previous threads in this forum? Also, just curious why write an AWT program and not use the more powerful Swing GUI library?

Comment: *"Buttons aren't magically able to do anything"* They are if you override deprecated methods like `public boolean action(Event e, Object o)` ;)  But to the OP (just in case you are confused on the matter) - ***Don't*** override deprecated methods.  It confuses people, if nothing else!

Comment: @Andrew: yikes -- I didn't see that he was doing that. Thanks Andrew!

Comment: I went looking for it, after noting in the question text that the code had worked earlier (WAG it is a class caching problem).

Comment: I tried adding ActionListener but in the parameter of ActionListener i give some parameter, Eclipse gives error and suggests to convert the parameter into ActionListener type... which still gives error

Answer (score 1):

First your class needs to implement the ActionListener Interface

```
public class main extends Applet implements ActionListener
```

This requires you to create the action(Event) function you already have.

Then you need to tell your buttons to use the class as their action listener

```
send.addActionListener(this);
```

That should make the click register.

Answer (score 1):

After I add imports, comment out a couple of redundant lines, add an applet tag, compile it and run it in applet viewer, I get output like..

```
connectedconnectedsentconnectedsent
```

So I'm thinking the problem at your end is that the browser is using old versions of the classes.  During development, it would be better to launch the applet using the applet viewer (or [Appleteer](http://pscode.org/appleteer/)), neither of which cache classes.

If the applet requires things for testing that are not supported by those tools (e.g. interaction with JS), make sure you have the Java Console configured to open when an applet (or JWS app.) is loaded.  There are commands (see the list in the starting output) to flush the cache.  Sometimes it can also be achieved by stopping and restarting the browser, but clearing the class cache is more reliable.

Comment: glad I partially nullified him/her.